# API with dotnet/angular spa app cannot be reached inside docker container but can be reached outside docker container

Tags: c#, angular, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

When I run my .net core3/angular spa application on my local machine everything works. But when I try to put everything in docker-compose while having 2 services one for front-end and one for API only the angular portion works. When angular makes a call to the API the endpoint cannot be reached.

here's my docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  test.ang.c:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}test.ang.c
    build:
      context: ./test-ang 
     # dockerfile: JrTech.Angular.Docker/Dockerfile
  test.ang.angular:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}test.ang.angular
    build:
      context: ./test-ang
      dockerfile: ./ClientApp/Dockerfile
      args:
        - skip_client_build=true
    ports:
      - "4200:4200" 
      - "49153:49153"
   
    volumes:
      - ./test-ang/ClientApp:/app
```

Dockerfile in test-ang/

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
# EXPOSE 4200
#EXPOSE 5001
# FROM node:10.15-alpine AS client 
# ARG skip_client_build=false 
# WORKDIR /app 
# COPY ./ClientApp . 
# RUN [[ ${skip_client_build} = true ]] && echo "Skipping npm install" || npm install 
# RUN [[ ${skip_client_build} = true ]] && mkdir dist || npm run-script build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
# RUN npm update
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["./test-ang.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./test-ang.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/test-ang"

# RUN echo ls 
RUN dotnet build "../test-ang.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "../test-ang.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "./test-ang.dll"]
```

Dockerfile in ClientApp (angular app):

```
FROM node:10.15-alpine AS client
EXPOSE 4200 49153
USER node
RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.1.0
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--port", "4200", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check", "--poll", "2000"]
```

Startup.cs

```
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {   // This starts up npm with server
                    // spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                    // spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://test.ang.angular:4200");
                }
            });
```

fetch-data.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'weatherforecast').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried using "localhost" instead of "test.ang.angular" ?

Comment: @Saurabh yes I did. The same thing happens still.

Comment: still experiencing this error?

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer:** 
Update angular code to access api using `test.ang.c` url such as `http://test.ang.c/api/values`. and you should be fine.

**Long answer:**

`UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` is only intended to be used during development, and not after you deploy it to docker. `IsDevelopment` is already taking care of that so you don't have to worry.

While working on docker there are two networks:
1. Inside docker (`docker network ls` command will show you that)
2. Host machine network.

`docker run -p <host port>:<docker port> <container name>`

When you are inside the docker network you'll have to use `<docker port>` like 80/4200 for accessing from the local computer you'll have to use `<host port>`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where to put http://test.ang.c in my angular app? I tried putting this first in the service that calls the api. The result was it could not find that url. I then put this inside the docker file and replaced the 0.0.0.0 part in the ng serve command. This resulted in not being able to render the application in my browser.

Comment: look for `http.get` call in your angular app. 

```export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'weatherforecast').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

the BASE_URL is a constant defined in another file in the above example. You can replace BASE_URL with the test.ang.c

Comment: So when I go to localhost:4200/fetch-data the app loads. I then added that url to base url and looked at my browser's network it calls ```Request URL: http://test.ang.c/weatherforecast
```.  Where ``` Referer: http://localhost:4200/fetch-data``` the request fails.

Comment: localhost:4200 is a node server hosting angular app.. 
you need to connect to kestrel which is hosting weather forecast webAPI.

running commands like `docker-compose port` could show you all the ports assigned to both the frontend and backend applicatoins.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your angular app to your backend, you're loading the frontend from the server to your browser and also hitting the backend from your browser, that is **from outside docker**.

Your current problem is that you're not exposing the backend port in the `docker-compose` file and your browser can't reach it. You can expose that port with the `ports:` directive you're already using but applying it to the other container.

By the way, I've had some troubles exposing ports 80 and 443 to outside docker, apparently they sometimes generate problems for being reserved ports, I'd recommend to expose other ones.